# play sound file only when div is visible?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

i am using jquery to fade in a div after 3 seconds. what i am trying to do now is set an if statement of some kind to say when the div "dashboard_right2" is visible then to play a sound clip.

at the moment i am using this html5 audio script that starts the sound file playing on page load, however i want the sound file to only play if the div "dashbaord_right2" is visible. could someone please show me how to do this, thanks.

audio code:

```
<audio src="assets/music/sound_file.mp3" autoplay>
</audio>
<script>
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
if (audio != null && audio.canPlayType && audio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg"))
{
audio.src = "audio/sample.mp3";
audio.play();
}
</script>
<audio src="data:audio/mpeg,ID3%02%00%00%00%00%..." autoplay>
</audio>
```

div that fades in after 3 seconds using jquery:

```
<script>
$('.dashboard_right2').hide(); // this or use css to hide the div
$('.dashboard_right2').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
</script>
```

Comment: How about `$('.dashboard_right2').delay(2000).faceIn('slow', function() { audio.play(); });`

Comment: Do you want to be able to hide/show dashboard_right2 repeatedly, or just do the initial fade in when the page loads?

Comment: i only need the initial fade in on page load

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
$('.dashboard_right2').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow', function() {
  // play your audio
  audio.play();
});
```

and

```
$('.dashboard_right2').hide();
audio.pause();
```

For example:

```
<div id="toggleMusic">Toggle Music</div>

<audio id="audio" src="assets/music/sound_file.mp3" autoplay>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#toggleMusic").click(function() {
   var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

   if($(".dashboard_right2").is(":visible")) {
      // hide the dashboard and pause the music
      $('.dashboard_right2').hide();
      audio.pause();
   } else {
      // show the dashboard and start the music
      $('.dashboard_right2').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow', function() {
         audio.play();
      });
   }
});
</script>
```

If you only need the `fadeIn()` on page load, then you should use the `toggle()` method to hide/show your element:

```
$('.dashboard_right2').toggle(0, function() {
   if($('.dashboard_right2').is(':visible')) {
      audio.play();
   } else {
      audio.pause();
   }
});
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to work, the html causes the audio file to play none the less :(

Comment: The above isn't tested, but should work. Have you tried setting `autoplay` to false? And what do you mean with "the html causes the audio file to play"? What isn't working?

Comment: @user3080996 - Oh, I just noticed that I had given the button the wrong id - it should be `toggleMusic` not `toggleButton`

Comment: @user3080996 - Also, I noticed that you couldn't pick up the `audio` element using an id, so you would have to do something like: `var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];`

Comment: i also am not wanting it to be a click function, as the divs fade in on page load, not on click. so do i need to change the toggle music function to a on load?

Comment: @user3080996 - I'm not going to write your code for you. I've showed you something that works and you may modify to suite your own needs. And it's kind of hard to understand how you actually want it to work? If you need more help you should update your question with further information=)